# Hide "Customize Form" Button on List Ribbon

Tags: 2010, feature, ribbon

I am trying to hide the "Customize Form" button on the List ribbon:

[image: Current Ribbon Settings]

I have created a feature that deploys an Elements.xml file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <HideCustomAction
    Id="HideInfoPathButton"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.List.CustomizeList.EditDefaultForms">
  </HideCustomAction>
</Elements>
```

But when I look at the ribbon, I get this:

[image: First try]

I have also tried this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
      Id="RemoveRibbonButton"
      Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
      RegistrationId="101"
      RegistrationType="List">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
            Location="Ribbon.List.CustomizeList.EditDefaultForms" />
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

with the same results.

I have also tried different Ribbon Control Identifiers for the Location attribute, but no matter what Identifier I use, the Form Web Parts button disappears.

I have used all three of the identifiers listed at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537543.aspx) for the Ribbon.List.CustomizeList group:

```
Ribbon.Library.CustomizeLibrary.AddButton
Ribbon.Library.CustomizeLibrary.EditList
Ribbon.Library.CustomizeLibrary.EditDefaultForms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked CAML (tested):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<CustomAction
  Id="RemoveRibbonButton"
  Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
  RegistrationId="0x"
  RegistrationType="ContentType">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition
        Location="Ribbon.List.CustomizeList.Controls.btnCustomizeList2" />
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
</CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
 </Elements>
```

Comment: can you post your code please . I have the same scenario but i want to hide only for a particular list